# How to compare the semantic similarity of text generated by large language models (GPT-3, BLOOM etc) to reference text?

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings, latent-semantic-analysis, text-generation, gpt

Large language models, such as GPT-3, BLOOM etc, can generate open-ended text. Say I want to prompt these models to answer a question. How can I compare the semantic similarity of the answer it provides me with a reference question?

Eg, if the prompt is, `'What should I eat for breakfast?'`, an example response that BLOOM will output is `'when should i eat lunch? etc.). Is there any way to get some suggestions from microsoft?'`

Say the reference answer to this question is `'You should eat a full English breakfast'`. How can I measure how different the BLOOM response is to the reference answer, in terms of its content?

Currently, I am encoding the text into BERT embeddings, and then computing cosine similarity between the output text and reference text. But the cosine similarity scores are quite low, because, as you can see, the BLOOM answer is not really on task. Should I be finetuning the BLOOM model somehow before trying to test semantic similarity?

The original BLOOM/GPT-3 models did quite well on SQuaD, but I don't seem to find that these models are answering questions very well without finetuning.

Answer (score 8):

> How can I compare the semantic similarity of the answer it provides me with a reference question?

With a text generation metric. See [Evaluation of Text Generation: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14799). Typical metrics: [TF-IDF cosine](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/120901/843), [Rouge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47045436/395857), Bleu, BertScore, Sentence-Bert, and more recently, [GPTScore](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.04166.pdf) and [G-Eval](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.16634). Note that they have some serious limitations when evaluating GPT output {1,2}.

---

References:

- {1} Goyal, Tanya, Junyi Jessy Li, and Greg Durrett. "[News Summarization and Evaluation in the Era of GPT-3.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.12356.pdf)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2209.12356 (2022).
- {2} Tianyi Zhang, Faisal Ladhak, Esin Durmus, Percy Liang, Kathleen McKeown, Tatsunori B. Hashimoto. [Benchmarking Large Language Models for News Summarization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.13848.pdf). arXiv:2301.13848.

---

Since comparing the semantic similarity of the predicted answer with a reference question has some limitations, one may look at complementing the analysis with a human evaluation. The following papers survey criteria used for human evaluation of generated texts (thanks Mengjiao Zhang for pointing me to refs {3,4}):

- {3} [A Survey of Evaluation Metrics Used for NLG Systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12009.pdf)
- {4} [Perturbation CheckLists for Evaluating NLG Evaluation Metrics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.05771.pdf) (unfortunately, they forgot about QA)

From {3}:

[image]